# JavaScript check if test on webpage then redirection

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a code that allows to know if in a specific web page, a text is written and if it is, redirect current page to another.

Basically the code check every 5 seconds if it is on the good web page [www.example.com/cart](http://www.example.com/cart) (because the code will be placed in the footer of the whole site and not the specific page), then he will check every 5 seconds if the text "validation" is written on the web page and if it is written, then redirect to web page [www.example.com/thanks](http://www.example.com/thanks)

My current code:

```
if ( document.URL.contains("http://www.example.com/cart") ) {
    document.body.textContent.search("Validation !");
    else {
    window.location = "http://www.example.com/cart";
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do this. Use backend redirect.

Comment: This is bad practice. Use `301/2` for a server-side redirect. Also, please don't use `lol` in your code; it gives us compile-time errors. ;)

Comment: I guess you are trying to implement a bot - please take a look at the documentation of https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval to check every X ms

Comment: What's not working? You can make it run every 5 seconds with `setInterval`.

Comment: why would somebody want to redirect a page after loading it!!

Comment: I 
I am doing this code because I need to redirect people on a landing page after their purchase to be able to place the tracking conversion code of linkedin. All because the page where we make the purchase is the same as the one where we finish it, and suddenly it is not possible to know who bought from Linkedin ads ...

Answer (score 0):

If you put the script into the footer, the script will be executed once per page load. You don't have to check every five seconds whether the URL *now* is the URL you want to forward from, it is sufficient to do it once.
I don't know how you expect your text "Validation !" to appear on your site, but if it is permanently on the site and not inserted by another JavaScript, you should also be able just to check once for the script, not every 5 seconds again and again.

So you can forward by just checking if you are on the page && the text is written on the site once.

```
if (document.URL.contains("http://www.example.com/cart") && document.body.textContent.contains("Validation !")) {
    window.location = "URL of site to forward to";
}
```

Please keep in mind that it is very bad style to solve something like this with a javascript in the footer on the site. It would be much more elegant to handle this directly in the backend.

Comment: "Validation" is not on the page at the beginning beacause its an iframe on the page with 4 steps before "validation" is show. I need to verify the url for not execute the script on every page and so crash the site